# Offerings made at Shradda

Tags: brahmanas, brahmacharya, shraddha

In Anushasana parva, Bhishma [explains](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a022.htm) about giving our taking offerings Shraddha by Bhrahmachari...

> If, having practised the vow of Brahmacharyya for the prescribed period (of twelve years) and acquired proficiency in the Vedas and their branches, a Brahmana himself solicits the offering made in Sraddhas and eats the same, he is regarded to fall away from his vow. The Sraddha, however, is not regarded as stained in any way.

and ...

> Those foolish men who do give unto a Brahmana observant of the vow of Brahmacharyya the offerings made in Sraddhas (unto one's deceased ancestors), have to go, O monarch into regions of great misery.

Please can someone explain these. Is it saying Brahmachari must not eat at Shraddha, and one must not offer at Shraddha to Brahmachari?

If not Brahmachari, who is eligible? Brahmanas following Brahmacharya vows are considered the superior. These Shraddha rules confusing me.

Comment: many yagnas are not allowed for brahmacharis, only for gruhasthas. gruhasthashram is actually considered the foundation ashram, because other 3 ashrams depend on them for living, just as kshatriya varna is considered foundation ashram, because other 3 varnas are protected by them.

Comment: @mar grahasta also supposed to live in brahmacharya vow? Is Bhishma talking about ashram and not the vow/way of life?

Comment: Bhishma is talking about ashram. Grushasthas can choose to follow brahmacharya even in married life by restricting copulation to specific days, but it is not mandatory. However, brahmacharis (non-married) folks are specifically restricted from many types of yagnas.

Answer (score -1):

Brahmchari means , he has sacrificed all maya element from his mind & body, as i mean.

Brahmchari means, who doesn't marry, or doesnot touch married couple, girls of age above 9 yrs.

Brahmchari is living in this world, but has no attachement to this world. As he is following brahmacharya VRUT.

Brahmchari is Sanyaasi, sarvam evam nyas, means sacrificed all worldly good things
like home, wife, vehicle, money , job etc... and has feeling that whole world is my
home. i can freely live anywhere without any physical item requirement.

So, he should not be called for eating Shraddha ritual food.

Brahmin, on another side is who does has attachement to this world and his
dharma. Brahmin, who does karma kand, namjap and comes in contact with many distress people, so maya tattva is sometime surrounded by him.

So Who is living in this world, and has some attachement like family, house , vehicle, attachement to money income, can be offered to eat shraddha food. It will not disturb brahmin , but WILL BREAK BRAHMCHARI'S LIFELONG VRUT.

### see this article :https://www.sanatan.org/hindi/a/237.html
Excerpts from this article :-

प्रत्येक मनुष्य जन्मतः शूद्र होता है अर्थात, शरीर की स्वच्छता ही करना सीखता है । आगे कर्म करने पर वह द्विज बनता है । द्वि अर्थात दो एवं ज अर्थात जन्म लेना । जनेऊ अंतर्गत संस्कारों के कारण पुत्र का एक प्रकार से जन्म ही होता है, अतः वह द्विज हो गया, ऐसा कहते हैं । ब्रह्मचारी का दूसरा जन्म (ब्रह्मजन्म) जनेऊ-बंधनसे चिह्नित होता है । उसका प्रतीक है जनेऊमेखला धारण करना । ऐसा कहते हैं कि इस जन्म में सावित्री उसकी माता तथा आचार्य उसके पिता हैं (मनुस्मृति, अध्याय २, श्‍लोक १७०) । द्विज होने पर वह गायत्री मंत्र का अधिकारी बनता है अर्थात, साधना करनेयोग्य होता है । अतः जनेऊ विधि करनी ही चाहिए; परंतु विवाह करना अनिवार्य नहीं है ।

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The rules insist on deriving the answer based on scriptures or great acharyas. Hope you have a good time on the site :)

Comment: *Brahmchari is Sanyaasi* What is your source on this? Are children who study Vedas in their gurukulams equivalent to sanyasis (they are required to practice brahmacharya)?